# Why don't my bash script create a mysql temporary table?

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm stumped why I cannot make the temp table in the bash script.

This works on the command prompt.

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE snorby.delete_me (
       SELECT  cid AS del_cid 
       FROM snorby.event 
       WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY) );
Query OK, 72 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 72  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from snorby.delete_me limit 2;
+---------+
| del_cid |
+---------+
|       4 |
|       5 |
+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE snorby.delete_me;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql>
```

But when I do that from the command line, intending to use it in the bash script, it does not make a table. Note: this root user has no password.

```
~$ sudo mysql -uroot -e "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE snorby.delete_me (SELECT cid AS del_cid FROM snorby.event WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY) );"
~$ sudo mysql -uroot -e "SELECT * FROM snorby.delete_me LIMIT 2;"
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'snorby.delete_me' doesn't exist
```

Lastly, if I put those commands in a .sql file and run them it also works fine. Example:

```
~$ mysql -uroot -e "SET @daystokeep=21; source snorby_del_old_by_days.sql;"
```

Thanks to barmar, I understand now. To run the whole thing from the command, it must be all one command, if using the temp table. Ex:

```
~$ sudo mysql -uroot -e "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE snorby.delete_me (SELECT cid AS del_cid FROM snorby.event WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY) ); SELECT * FROM snorby.delete_me LIMIT 2;  DROP TABLE snorby.delete_me;"
```

Or use a regular table.

I thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want the table to persist between MySQL invocations, why are you making it temporary? What do you think temporary means?

Answer (score 3):

It *does* create the table. And then it closes the session, which destroys the table. Find another way to do this.

Comment: For reference, see the [MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html), 'Temporary Tables' section.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your code to the following should allow it to work:

```
~$ sudo mysql -uroot -e "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE snorby.delete_me (SELECT cid AS del_cid FROM snorby.event WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY) ); SELECT * FROM snorby.delete_me LIMIT 2;"
```